# Matlab string concatenation for file creation

Tags: matlab, file, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm following an online course to learn and practice matlab. In the course, the guys writes:

```
basefilename = 'testfile';
filename = [basefilename num2str(1) ".mat"]
```

and Matlab returns:

```
testfile1.mat
```

However, when enter the same input, I get the following as an output:

```
filename = 

  1×3 string array

    "testfile"    "1"    ".mat"
```

I tried a more usual concatenating method by inputting

```
filename = [basefilename + "1" + ".mat"]
```

And go the correct output:

```
testfile1.mat
```

However, when changing the `"1"` to `num2str(1)` (in order to replace the number by a variable that can vary in a for loop later on):

```
filename = [basefilename + num2str(1) + ".mat"]
```

I get a completely different output:

```
filename = 

  1×8 string array

    "165.mat"    "150.mat"    "164.mat"    "165.mat"    "151.mat"    "154.mat"    "157.mat"    "150.mat"
```

I was wondering if someone could explain why each input methods returns such drastically different outputs. It seems to me like all three methods should return the same thing...

Comment: Maybe mixing of character arrays (`'test'`) and actual strings (`"test"`) is a problem here? See [Create String Arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) from the MATLAB documentation for further reading.

Comment: The online course likely is written for Octave, which treats `"` as if it were `'`. You should translate all their double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Taking a wild guess at your workflow, I think you could benefit from the implicit conversion that plus with strings can do. "basefilename" + 1 + ".mat". If you wanted to create an array of filenames you could do "basefilename" + (1:10)' + ".mat"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
basefilename = 'testfile';
```

basefilename is a char array (note the single quotes). Double quotes implies a single string variable.

```
filename = [basefilename num2str(1) '.mat']
```

will yield the desired results by concatenating arrays of char's while

```
filename = ["stuff" ".mat"]
```

will generate an array of 2 strings, and as you noted

```
filename = ["stuff" + ".mat"]
```

yields a single concatenated variable of type string.

The example you showed with

```
filename = ['chars'  ".strings"]

filename = ['chars' + "strings"]
```

will cast the char array (single quoted) to a string and then perform the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try remove the '+' and the "". So:

filename = [basefilename num2str(1) '.mat']

The '+' isn't used for concatenating in MATLAB, and there is a difference between ' and " in MATLAB ([String indexing in MATLAB: single vs. double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619191/string-indexing-in-matlab-single-vs-double-quote))